# pkg_resources is deprecated as an API

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, deprecation-warning

When I try to install from a .tar.gz package, while making warnings into errors:

```
python -W error -m pip install /some/path/nspace.pkga-0.1.0.tar.gz
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 98, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 342, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 175, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
    return next(matches, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 183, in <genexpr>
    matches = (
              ^
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
    for dist in self._iter_distributions():
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 176, in _iter_distributions
    for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 144, in find_eggs
    yield from self._find_eggs_in_dir(location)
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 111, in _find_eggs_in_dir
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import find_distributions
  File "/opt/util/nspace1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 121, in <module>
    warnings.warn("pkg_resources is deprecated as an API", DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API
```

pip seems to have vendored in a deprecated package. The pip code responsible is in `pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py` in class `Environment`:

```
    def _iter_distributions(self) -> Iterator[BaseDistribution]:
        finder = _DistributionFinder()
        for location in self._paths:
            yield from finder.find(location)
            for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
                # _emit_egg_deprecation(dist.location)  # TODO: Enable this.
                yield dist
            # This must go last because that's how pkg_resources tie-breaks.
            yield from finder.find_linked(location)
```

If I comment out the nested for loop (doing the find_eggs) thinks work fine: I get no error and a working package installed.

How do I monkeypatch that `Environment` instance from my setup.py file?

This is Python 3.11.3 (so it should be using importlib.metadata and not pkg_resources) on macOS, pip==23.1, setuptools==67.6.1

Background: I am just trying this out on an example package, the reason for this is based on a bug report for my `ruamel.yaml` package, where it is build in such a less forgiving environment. I could of course say don't use `-W error`, but I rather solve this, by not invoking the offending, unused code in the first place

Comment: I feel like *pip* should remove the deprecation notice from its vendored copy of *pkg_resources*. Have you tried engaging the discussion with *pip*'s maintainers on [*pip*'s ticket tracker](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues) or checked if it has already been reported? -- Well... seems like there is a related discussion already: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11975 -- Reading this and related tickets, it seems like a bugfix release *23.1.1* will be published very soon, which might fix this.

Comment: That might be an idea, but I didn't see this as a bug, just something else in Python packaging to work around.

Comment: [*pip 23.1.1* has been released](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v23-1-1). Maybe it is better for your use case now.

Comment: @sinoroc changing pip to 23.1.1 removes the problem, thanks for pointing it out. Not sure what the developers are doing with these tools. pip 22.3 would barf on a different deprecation (setup.py no longer supported), now this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a [related discussion on *pip*'s ticket tracker](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11975).

It seems like this issue has been solved in [*pip 23.1.1*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v23-1-1): "[*Revert `pkg_resources` (via `setuptools`) back to `65.6.3`*](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/11976)".

And [*pip 23.1.2*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v23-1-2) seems to [vendor the new *setuptools* (and `pkg_resources`) as expected but without the deprecation warnings](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/11997) (see also this [message](https://discuss.python.org/t/announcement-pip-23-1-release/25844/6)).

Comment: pip==23.1.1 doesn't show the problem

Comment: I've pip 23.1.2 and unfortunately, I'm getting the error.

Comment: 23.2.1 shows a deprecated warning.

Comment: 23.3.1 also shows a deprecation warning

Comment: I also found that upgrading pip didnt hide this message, so instead I manually specified this in my package dependencies: `"setuptools<=65.6.3"`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, with `Python 3.11` from Scoop, and using `csvkit` installed with `pip 23.3.1` also showed a deprecation warning, but upgrading setuptools to `69.0.2` solved this issue.

Answer (score -2):

I had similar deprecated messages which where only annoying. I solved it using

```
pip uninstall setuptools
```

and reinstalled the version which don't have these deprecated warnings.

```
pip install setuptools==66.1.1
```

Version Sources: [setuptools versions](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/66.1.1/)
Version of setuptools which added the deprecated warning: [v67.3.0](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v67-3-0)